# Word choice - Grammar!

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs, synonyms, descriptive-grammar

I came across these questions in an old English Language book from the 70s and was wondering if one form of the following sentences is more correct than the other.

*Only the team with the lowest service ratings (is/are) referred to training with human resources.*

and

*The person whose engine is sputtering is usually the person (who's/that's) most inclined to visit the mechanic.*

and

*Because of the amount of gas in the canister, the fumes spread (rapidly about/quickly through) the room.*

In reference to the first question, I like the use of "is", because I am under the impression that if you remove "with the lowest service ratings", then the sentence would still be grammatically correct?

Regarding the second question I feel that "who's" is more grammatically correct because "The person", and "who's" are in more agreement than "that's." I feel "that's" refers more to an object, whereas "who's" in this case, is more appropriate since we are referring to "The person."

For the third sentence, I like the usage of "rapidly about" more than "quickly through." I feel that "quickly through" is implying that the gas is starting at point A, and exiting at a point B. "Rapidly about" suggests the gas expands and spreads without a definitive end, if that makes sense.

Am I wrong in any of my assessments? Again, these came from an English learning book dated 1972, so their rules regarding grammar might be different from present day!

Comment: 1972 is in the lifetimes of many a user here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first question "is" is strictly correct, the subject (team) being in the singular. This rule is less observed than it was and may feel somewhat formal now.

*Only the team with the lowest service ratings is referred to training with human resources.*

(I'm surprised to see "human resources" used in 1972 when "personnel" was more common.)

In the second question I think "who's" is correct for the reasons you give.

*The person whose engine is sputtering is usually the person who's most inclined to visit the mechanic.*

But the sentence seems too long, considering how little is being said. And the repeating sounds ***person whose*** ... ***person who's*** is weak.

It might sound more natural if we leave out "who's":

*The person whose engine is sputtering is usually the person most inclined to visit the mechanic.*

We might also get rid of the second "person" and say,

*The person whose engine is sputtering is usually the one most inclined to visit the mechanic.*

Either option in question three would be grammatically correct. There is nothing to choose between *rapidly* and *quickly*, but the word *about* suggests a scattering rather than a steady progression. I prefer "spread quickly through" or  "the fumes quickly filled the room."

Answer (score 1):

I believe your analysis to be correct for all three.

I need not repeat all the definitions in the Cambridge dictionary but *through* has the connotations that you suggest.

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/through)

I suspect the compilers of the questions were testing for understanding of the difference between *through* and *throughout*.

Throughout = *in every part, or during the whole period of*

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/throughout)

Comment: I know. Happens to all of us though. +1